# How do I change the background color of the groovy console window?

Tags: groovy

The groovy console is a white background with black text and is not the easiest on the eyes.  How can I change the colors?

Comment: It seems the only way would be to change it in the source code. I am sure they would accept a pull request for adding this as a configurable feature. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is by:
`Right Click on Taskbar -> Select Properties -> Colors -> Set RGB config`

Make sure you're running the Groovy shell as administrator for the changes to take place.

My RGB Config:

- Screen Text: 157, 254, 254
- Screen Background: 27, 134, 144
- Pop Up Text: 124, 222, 222
- Pop Up Background: 40, 50, 50

Also you may want to go the Terminal Tab and customize the cursor types and colors as needed.